# VBA: sql, retrieving the multiple values

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I my fist excel sheet I have a key values, like:

I would like to retrieve the values from the database (one key have a multiples values in database like) and put this on the second sheet:

I dont know how to make a sql joint beacause I'm retrieving only the first value. My code is:

imgur.com/j9Ay5.png

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you build your SQL query first using the data, and *then* run it against the recordset/write out in one attempt. It should be much faster than doing these one record at a time.

A) Concatenate the data in the range into a string, surrounded by single-quotes and with commas between the values (https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/)

B) Change your SQL query to be

```vb
"select  isin.CD_RGA, val.D_COTATION from DB_VALEUR_RGA val, DB_RGA isin " &_
"where isin.CD_RGA IN (" & YOUR_CONCAT_STRING_HERE & ")" & _
" and isin.IS_RGA=val.IS_RGA and (val.D_COTATION in ('28/08/2020') or val.D_COTATION > '13/10/2020') and val.D_COTATION not in ('17/10/2020')"
```

C) After you open it, dump the values at once in the range; don't do this one cell at a time. See this [little tip](https://www.xylos.com/en/learning/blog/tip-7-save-time-processing-data-excel-vba) for additional samples.

```vb
With Worksheets("OUTPUT")
    .Cells.ClearContents
    .Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset RECSET
End With
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you, a good idea! I don't know how to put the result, I  added the error to my message with question

Comment: You can see your variable doesn’t have single quotes around them. You need to surround the values with quotes for the SQL to work. Please see my link to learn how to do that. You want the value of Code_Isin to look like ‘FR001’, ‘FR002’, ‘FR003’, ‘FR004’

Comment: Yes, I did that (I put the new image), it's just not appear in control windows

Comment: I suppose that probleme is in output definition, but I don't know how to correct it: Worksheets("OUTPUT").Cells(1, 1).Value = Code_Isin
    Worksheets("OUTPUT").Cells(1, 2).Value = RECSET.Fields("D_COTATION").Value

Comment: I added more clarity on how to save the data. Please research RECORDSET online if you need additional help, as this is fundamental vb behavior. If you have an error, please include the error message (I don't see one in your post). Please upvote or accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: Hello, Thank you, I put the image with error, it indicates that type of variables  is incorrect and in conflict with other variables.